# Java 11 HttpClient Handshake Failure

Tags: java, java-http-client

I'm having issues retrieving the content from some HTTPS sites using the Java 11 HTTPClient. Here's the code I'm using:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(URI.create("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"))
  .build();

HttpResponse<byte[]> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
System.out.println(response.statusCode());
System.out.println(new String(response.body()));
```

When trying to download the source of Wikipedia, I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

If I use the same code but change the source URL to `https://www.google.com`, it works fine. From a bit of Googling, this makes it sound to me like it's probably an issue with differing crypto algorithms (although I don't know that), but it's not clear to me how to fix it. I've tried a few solutions that have been suggested on other StackOverflow questions, but haven't found one that works for me or a reliable guide to debugging the problem.

Can someone please point me in the direction of what I can try to fix the issue?

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it to http?

Comment: Doing so returns a 301 status code (redirect), to the HTTPS version. So I either don't get any content besides the redirect headers, or I get the error above if I follow the redirect.

Comment: When I googled it, I found something about the security. Maybe there's a way you can turn it off on the httpClient?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Just copy-pasted this code in `OpenJDK 11` environment, and it works fine. Anything related to the network filtering? firewall?..

Comment: i am not getting any issue with that version, it is working fine in my mac with same version

Comment: Thanks for confirming it's my environment rather than the code. The computer isn't behind anything fancy in terms of firewalls, and accessing the URL directly in a browser works fine. I'll try reinstalling my Java environment and see if that works.

Comment: Reinstalling Java, as well as trying different versions, hasn't helped - does anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: I'd suggest to set `-Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log=errors,requests,headers,ssl` on the java command line. If that doesn't provide enough clue you could also try to add `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused problem on your environment, but just to test the URL I ran a different Http client using Java 8, and it worked just fine. Just in case you would want to try this Http client Here is the code and the info where to get the client:

```
    private static void testHttpClient() {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.setConnectionUrl("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
        String result;
        try {
            ByteBuffer buff = client.sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(HttpMethod.GET);
            result = new String(buff.array());
//          result = client.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.GET);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, "com.mot.");
        }
    }
```

This code worked with both options: you can comment the two lines

```
            ByteBuffer buff = client.sendHttpRequestForBinaryResponse(HttpMethod.GET);
            result = new String(buff.array());
```

and uncomment the line

```
//          result = client.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.GET);
```

And it also works.
The HttpClient used here comes from MgntUtils Open Source library. That library is available as Maven Artifacts Maven Central [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) And also on [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc). Javadoc for The library could be seen [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/).

**Disclaimer:** The library is written by me